# Was the Skyrim Intro dialogue ever changed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Skyrim was released in 2011 and I played it when it was new.

I turned it back on recently and watched the legendary **Hey you, you're finally awake** opening scene. The player character is tied up on a wagon with Ulfric Stormcloak, a Stormcloak soldier named Ralof, and a horse thief named Lokir.

> **Lokir:** Damn you Stormcloaks. Skyrim was fine until you came along. Empire was nice and lazy. If they hadn't been looking for you, I could've stolen that horse and be halfway to Hammerfell. You there. You and me - we shouldn't be here. It's these Stormcloaks the Empire wants.
>
> **Ralof:** We are all brothers **and sisters** in binds now,

The **and sisters** part sticks out at me. Was it in the original script? Or is it an edit since the game came out?

It is appropriate since the player race/gender is not decided at this point. Of course if you decide you're playing a man the line then sounds strange. It would make more sense to edit the horse thief to be a woman. That way Ralof is referring to himself, the horse thief and my undetermined friend over here. . . .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As videos of the Skyrim intro such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsRA5BG3N8E) easily prove, the dialogue on launch day was exactly as you quoted it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Brothers and sisters are fitting seeing that on the other carts there are female prisoners. And as Wrigglenite stated in his answer there is a video that shows it was always intended to be so.